# Photoshop Color Picker Hexadecimal use capital letter

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there any configuration on Photoshop to make color picker use capital letter?

[image: Color Picker]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. Photoshop simply doesn't care about case in the hex field. You can type in all uppercase if you want. It won't make any difference.

Comment: yes it is won make any difference in Photoshop, but i prefer to have it in UPPERCASE format

Comment: Then use caps lock :)

Comment: @GusDeCooL: any particular reason behind "all uppercase", beside personal preference? I'm asking out of curiosity :)

Comment: @thebodzio i use netbeans for Website Development. I prefer have have color code in Uppercase Hexadecimal, for me it easier to read.

Comment: @GusDeCooL: I see. In that case I'd look for/write myself a Netbeans plugin to convert pasted string to uppercase if it's 6 hexadecimal digits.